# Database create statement not making second table?

Tags: android, sql

I get an error when trying to insert into TABLE_EVENTS but no problem inserting/querying TABLE_CONTACTS.  Here is my create string:

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 

            "create table "+ TABLE_CONTACTS + "( " + COLUMN_CONTACTS_LOOKUP
            + " text primary key, " + COLUMN_CONTACTS_ADDED
            + " real not null);" +

            " create table "+ TABLE_EVENTS +"( "+ COLUMN_ID +" integer primary key autoincrement, "+
            COLUMN_EVENTS_TITLE + " text not null, "+COLUMN_EVENTS_START_TIME+" real not null, "+
            COLUMN_EVENTS_END_TIME+ " real, "+COLUMN_EVENTS_TYPE+" integer not null, "+COLUMN_EVENTS_START_LONG+" integer, "+
            COLUMN_EVENTS_START_LAT+" integer);";
```

Called with

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }
```

And my insert is

```
public long createEvent(String title, long start, long end, int type, int long_, int lat){
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(COLUMN_EVENTS_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(COLUMN_EVENTS_START_TIME, start);
        initialValues.put(COLUMN_EVENTS_END_TIME, end);
        initialValues.put(COLUMN_EVENTS_TYPE, type);
        initialValues.put(COLUMN_EVENTS_START_LAT, lat);
        initialValues.put(COLUMN_EVENTS_START_LONG, long_);

        return  mDb.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, initialValues);
    }
```

Comment: If you're talking about "errors", then you should post the logcat of the exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `SQLiteDatabase` class only allows one `CREATE` statement in your `DATABASE_CREATE` string. If you want to create more than one table, the trick is to prepare multiple creation strings, then call them one by one in your `onCreate` method:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
  db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
  db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);
}
```

You're getting an error because your events table was never created.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite only allows one SQL command at any time.  You need split out your create statements in to individual strings and execute them one by one.

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_1 =
 "create table "+ TABLE_CONTACTS + "( " + COLUMN_CONTACTS_LOOKUP
            + " text primary key, " + COLUMN_CONTACTS_ADDED
            + " real not null);";


private static final String CREATE_TABLE_2 =
"create table "+ TABLE_EVENTS +"( "+ COLUMN_ID +" integer primary key autoincrement, "+
 COLUMN_EVENTS_TITLE + " text not null, "+COLUMN_EVENTS_START_TIME+" real not null, "+
 COLUMN_EVENTS_END_TIME+ " real, "+COLUMN_EVENTS_TYPE+" integer not null, "+COLUMN_EVENTS_START_LONG+" integer, "+
 COLUMN_EVENTS_START_LAT+" integer);";


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_1);
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem. Boy was that a headache.

Create one string for every new table and call `db.execSQL(query)` on each of them! It seems to be some problems with using the ; delimiter.